# The subdomain of Amateur Radio?

Tags: discussion, subdomains, specific-site

Why is the subdomain for the site Amateur Radio (Beta) `ham.stackexchange.com`?

Answer (score 8):

Because amateur radio is also known as [ham radio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_radio) - from Wikipedia:

> The term "ham radio" was first a pejorative that mocked amateur radio operators with a 19th-century term for being bad at something, like "ham-fisted" or "ham actor". It had already been used for bad wired telegraph operators.
>
> Subsequently, the community adopted it as a welcome moniker, much like the "Know-Nothing Party", or other groups and movements throughout history. Other, more entertaining explanations have grown up throughout the years, but they are apocryphal.